# Converting foreach loop to LINQ query breaks code

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, resharper

Resharper is suggesting me to convert the following code:

```
Type myType = typeof(FooEntity);
PropertyInfo nameProp = myType.GetProperty("Name");
PropertyInfo valueProp = myType.GetProperty("Id");

using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
    foreach (object obj in dbContext.Set(myType))
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = nameProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
            Value = valueProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
        });
    }
}
```

To

```
Type myType = typeof(FooEntity);
PropertyInfo nameProp = myType.GetProperty("Name");
PropertyInfo valueProp = myType.GetProperty("Id");

using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
{
    items.AddRange(from object obj in dbContext.Set(myType)
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = nameProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
                       Value = valueProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
                   });
}
```

But after accepting ReSharper's suggestion, I am getting an `InvalidCastException` with

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>
> Message=Cannot Create a `DbSet<Object>` from a non-generic `DbSet` for objects of type '`FooEntity`'
>
> Source=EntityFramework
>
> StackTrace: (Skipped for brevity)

What's wrong with ReSharper's suggestion?

Comment: Why dbContext.Set(myType) was changed to dbContext.Set(selectListType)?

Comment: Is "selectListType" a typo, or is it a different Type instance?

Comment: @VladimirSachek: Beat me by 2 seconds ;)

Comment: oops, sorry that was a typo

Comment: Are you sure nothing else changed? i.e.: If you revert it back to a loop, does it work as expected?

Comment: Could you try to use dbContext.Set(myType).Cast<FooEntity>()? or dbContext.Set<FooEntity>(myType)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt yes it works as expected when I use a `foreach` loop and call the `Add` method

Comment: @VladimirSachek actually i was trying to let the caller pass the `Type` instead of hardcoding the generic argument to `FooEntity`. This is just some demo code to show the issue.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark. Try removing the `object` type in the query expression, so its `from obj in dbContext.Set(myType)` ...

Comment: @mikez nope this does not work, I get a compile error: `The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query.`

Comment: I suspect the issue is related to the fact that when a type is specified on the range parameter in a query expression it is translated from `from T x in e` to `from x in (e).Cast<T>()` and `DbSet` has its own `Cast` method. This method fails for some reason. What happens if you change the `foreach` to `object obj in dbContext.Set(myType).Cast<object>()`? That shouldn't make a difference most of the time, but something is not normal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I am getting a bit another error: 
    `System.InvalidCastException` : Cannot create a `DbSet<Object>` from a non-generic `DbSet` for objects of type.

The problem here is that linq expression forces `DbSet` to implement `IEnumerable<object>` which is not possible, because it implements only `IEnumerable`. To proof that the following code works fine

```
IEnumerable dbSet = dbContext.Set(myType);
items.AddRange(from object obj in dbSet
               select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = nameProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
                        Value = valueProp.GetValue(obj).ToString(),
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks it works! It really bugs me that `DbSet` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`